# ошибка подключения. Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/source/Sources» .не могу использовать команды для дальнейшей работы

Tags: ubuntu, update, sudo

ошибка при `sudo apt update`

```
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/source/Sources», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)

было больше ошибок их решили ранее , но так некто не смог помочь,решил снова написать. проверял везде где можно но никак.
```

**ранеее!**

*исправить удалось большую часть, но всё ещё не работает как надо,осталось немного)
***оставил то что было для других 0_о***

не могу установить нужные обновления для дальнейшей работы.. спасибо за понимание*

```
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/source/Sources», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/binary-amd64/Packages», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/binary-i386/Packages», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/i18n/Translation-ru», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/i18n/Translation-en», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/i18n/Translation-ru_RU», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/dep11/Components-amd64.yml», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/dep11/icons-48x48.tar», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/dep11/icons-64x64.tar», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/cnf/Commands-amd64», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list**`введите сюда код`

```
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates InRelease universe
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe main restricted multiverse
```

*curl -s http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease | head -15*

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: bionic
Version: 18.04
Codename: bionic
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:37:48 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Bionic 18.04
MD5Sum:
 32a92a5c20f378d42dd2d2f4f28f6637        628836439 Contents-amd64
 53c6a594819b51a5755f88b45d1eff7f         37766986 Contents-arm64.gz
```

*удалил*

```
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

*sudo apt update *

```
Все пакеты имеют последние версии.
W: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «InRelease/source/Sources», так как в репозитории «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease» отсутствует компонент «InRelease» (возможно, компонент указан с ошибкой в sources.list?)
```

**всё это нужно чтобы mongodb работало.. но оно не хочет, список ошибок за 10часов уже раз 20 поменялся**

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mongodb-clients : Зависит: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 но он не может быть установлен
                   Зависит: libboost-iostreams1.71.0 но он не может быть установлен
                   Зависит: libboost-program-options1.71.0 но он не может быть установлен
                   Рекомендует: mongo-tools но он не может быть установлен
 mongodb-org : Зависит: mongodb-org-tools но он не будет установлен
               Конфликтует: mongodb но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
               Конфликтует: mongodb-clients но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
               Конфликтует: mongodb-server но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
 mongodb-org-database : Зависит: mongodb-org-shell но он не будет установлен
                        Зависит: mongodb-org-server но он не будет установлен
                        Зависит: mongodb-org-mongos но он не будет установлен
                        Зависит: mongodb-org-database-tools-extra но он не будет установлен
                        Конфликтует: mongodb но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
                        Конфликтует: mongodb-clients но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
                        Конфликтует: mongodb-server но 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.2 должен быть установлен
 mongodb-server-core : Зависит: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 но он не может быть установлен
                       Зависит: libboost-program-options1.71.0 но он не может быть установлен
E: Ошибка: pkgProblemResolver::Resolve привёл к появлению сломанных пакетов. Это может быть вызвано зафиксированными пакетами.
```

```
 sudo apt install libboost-filesystem1.71.0
[sudo] пароль для denis991: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
Пакет libboost-filesystem1.71.0 недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «libboost-filesystem1.71.0» не найден кандидат на установку
```

*после изменений  с использованием сравнения
ls /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}*

```
root@denis991:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}; lsb_release -a
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish-backports main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://mirror.logol.ru/ubuntu/ impish-backports main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties


==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_canonical_com_ubuntu-hirsute.list <==
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-hirsute.list <==
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse universe restricted main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse universe restricted main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ru_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-hirsute.list <==
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_security_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-hirsute.list <==
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main universe restricted multiverse

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_security_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_-hirsute.list <==
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe


==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list <==
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list <==
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse # заблокировано при обновлении до impish

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main # заблокировано при обновлении до impish
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Impish Indri (development branch)
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы привели список предупреждений. а проблема-то у вас какая?

Comment: Покажите файл `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: И вывод команды `curl -s http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease | head -15`

Comment: Удалите или закомментируйте первую строчку. Судя по остальным строчкам у вас не `bionic`, а `hirsuite`

Comment: Всю строку уберите. Зачем вам обновления бионика на хирсуте?

Comment: Так проблема ещё проявляется?

Comment: Проверьте файлы в папке `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: так вы всё-таки уточните, пожалуйста, в чём именно у вас проблема. что именно у вас не работает или работает неправильно?

Comment: ага, возьмём первый из неустанавливающихся. `$ sudo apt install libboost-filesystem1.71.0` что выдаёт? // кстати, приложите, пожалуйста, и вывод `$ head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}; lsb_release -a`

Comment: для начала вам надо вычистить все эти авгиевы конюшни — `$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`. убрать всё, не являющееся официальными репозиториями именно той версии дистрибутива, которая у вас сейчас установлена: ubuntu 21.10

Comment: сделал что смог

Comment: у вас так и остались подключенными репозитории **не для вашей версии дистрибутива**: hirsute, focal, bionic. и остались подключенными левые репозитории: с сайтов microsoft, google, mongodb. поотключайте (закомментировав строки или удалив файлы) всё это непотребство. а потом уже можете переходить и к наведению порядка в **уже** установленных пакетах.

Comment: уточните где остались

Comment: удалить все файлы  ? etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: на всякий случай перед удалением сохраните где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге копии этих файлов. // p.s. чтобы ваш собеседник (не являющийся автором вопроса) получал оповещения о вашем комментарии, адресованном ему, надо упомянуть этого пользователя. например: `@dengood` (жабаскрипт сам подставит варианты имён, достаточно начать их писать после символ `@`).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin попробуем учиться я программированием только начал заниматься и не много в подобных чатах зависал по этому спасибо за обучение данных вопросов!

Comment: аналогичная ошибка была с этим файлом
deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /
deb-src https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла только полная переустановка ubuntu. как и советовал @aleksandr barakin
сделал резервную копию.
было потрачено более 20 часов другого выхода не было.
спасибо всем за советы, от души!!